Run exe file with wine and It show text as square

When I install exe file with wine It will appear squre box as texts and I cannot read It. How to solve this problem?
Thank you for all answers.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details, which is the starting point to fixing issues & accurate suggestions. Boxes (instead of text) can appear when your system doesn't include the required font installed.

@guiverc I use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

guiverc I use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Please edit your question to contain the new info
